# term.h : header not found

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have a little piece of code for linux terminal capabilities, it uses the term.h header file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <term.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
      setupterm("unlisted",fileno(stdout),(int*)0); 
      printf("Done.\n");
}
```

but when I try to compile it I get fatal error: term.h : No such file or directory

What should I do? Where's the problem

Comment: What about installing the missing package?

Comment: what's the name of the package?

Comment: A quick search on a well-known search engine led me to this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=23001. Depending on your linux distribution, you may need to install the `-dev` package for `libncurses`.

Comment: But when I execute dpkg-query --search curses.h I got no found matching results :/ btw im on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @koder16 can you try to install the libncurses5-dev library

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, @AIL's suggestion matches that on the forum I linked to.

Comment: For centos 7, I install ncurses-devel to be solved.

Answer (score 12):

On Ubuntu, download and install the libncurses5-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

then compile:

```
gcc my_program.c -o my_program -lncurses
```